# I need help on LookupOrderedRows?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to match records and return value. I have DE1 and DE2, in DE1 I have  col names "AgencyCode", "AgencyPhone" and "ProducerCode" in DE2 I have "AgencyCode" "ProducerCode" and "AgencyPhone". In DE1 some of agency phone numbers are blank, so for that record I need to print in email Phonenumber from DE2 where AgencyCode and ProducerCode both matches in DE1.

I was thinking to do something like this but I am lost :). How do I match two column values (ProducerCode and AgencyCode)?

```
SET @A1 = AttributeValue("AGENCYPHONE") 
SET @A2 = Lookup("DE1","AgencyCode","PolicyNumber",PolicyNumber) 
SET @A3 = LookupOrderedRows("DE2",0,"AgencyPhone desc","ProducerCode", @A2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, I'd use [`LookUpOrderedRows`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) to lookup on both DE1 and DE2.

**Logic:**

The first lookup will check if there is any records with matching `PolicyNumber`, if so then it will grab the `AgencyPhone` from DE1.

If `AgencyPhone` is not empty and found in DE1 it will grab the rest of the field from DE1, however if not found it will do a second Lookup on DE2 matching `AgencyCode` and `ProducerCode`.

Then if a record is found it will then grab the `email` and `Phonenumber` in DE2, assuming the fields you have mentioned are correct.

**Sample Code:**

```
SET @A2 = LookupOrderedRows('DE1','1','AgencyCode DESC','PolicyNumber',PolicyNumber)
IF RowCount(@A2) > 0  THEN
    SET @A2Row = Row(@A2,1)
    SET @AgencyPhone = Field(@A2Row, 'AgencyPhone')
    IF NOT EMPTY(@AgencyPhone) AND Length(@AgencyPhone) > 0 THEN
        SET @ProducerCode = Field(@A2Row, 'ProducerCode')
        SET @AgencyCode = Field(@A2Row, 'AgencyCode')
    ELSE
        SET @A3 = LookupOrderedRows('DE2','1','AgencyCode DESC','AgencyCode',@AgencyCode,'ProducerCode',@ProducerCode)
        IF RowCount(@A3) > 0 THEN
            SET @A3Row = Row(@A3,1)
            SET @email = Field(@A3Row, 'email')
            SET @Phonenumber = Field(@A3Row, 'Phonenumber')
        ELSE
            SET @message = 'No record found with matching AgencyCode and ProducerCode in DE2'
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ELSE
    SET @message = 'No PolicyNumber number found in DE1'
ENDIF
```

Comment: Thank you Brad. Its great. Just a one minor change in your code, maybe helpful anyone else looking for same solution. 
IF RowCount(A3) > 0 THEN will going to be like IF RowCount(@A3) > 0 THEN

Comment: Thank you @sohail. Also can you please accept and up vote the solution. Thank you